# QBasic - How to find this value?

Tags: formula, qbasic

If we have `M` as follows:

`M = 1+2+3+5+6+7+9+10+11+13+...+n`

What would be the `QBasic` program to find `M`.

I have done the following so far, but is not returning me the expected value

```
INPUT "ENTER A VALUE FOR N"
SUM = 0
FOR I = 1 TO N
IF I MOD 4 = 0
SUM = SUM + I
NECT I
```

How should I go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed the equality operator. Try this:

```
INPUT "ENTER A VALUE FOR N"
SUM = 0
FOR I = 1 TO N
IF I MOD 4 <> 0
    SUM = SUM + I
NEXT I
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to write a program, or at least no need to use loops.

Sum of first n natural numbers:

```
sum_1 = n * (n + 1) / 2
```

Sum of multiples of 4 < n:

```
sum_2 = 4 * (n / 4) * (n / 4 + 1) / 2 = 2 * (n / 4) * (n / 4 + 1)
```

The result is `sum_1 - sum_2`:

```
sum = sum_1 - sum_2 = n * (n + 1) / 2 - 2 * (n / 4) * (n / 4 + 1)
```

NB: `/` = integer division

Answer (score 0):

This snip calculates the sum of integers to n skipping values divisible by 4.

```
PRINT "Enter upper value";
INPUT n
' calculate sum of all values
FOR l = 1 TO n
    x = x + l
NEXT
' remove values divisible by 4
FOR l = 0 TO n STEP 4
    x = x - l
NEXT
PRINT "Solution is:"; x
```

Comment: Uses 2 loops to calculate sum of values without ones divisible by 4.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!